# Looking for good external RAID enclosure

Tags: case, raid, drive-enclosure

I am looking for an simple external RAID enclosure that meets the following specs:

- 3x 3.5" or more
- RAID5
- JBOD
- compatible with 12 TByte drives
- compatible with Linux
- average performance
- not very loud (= large fan or fans with slow speed)
- connect via USB3 to host system; LAN is nice but not necessary
- Kensington slot for locks or other possibility to attach a steel cable

Whatever product I could find online seems to lack essential criteria. Either the enclosure is well built, then it exhibits slow and even erratic data transfer speeds. Or it is well built but does not support 12 TByte drives. Or it is quite perfect but the fan is very noisy. Et cetera.

Does anyone know of a well built product?

Comment: What are you connecting this enclosure to?